# Upstart - Graphic window not displaying

Tags: python, linux, upstart, vnc

I've got this python script that opens up a VNC session through a graphical window.  It sits there blocking waiting for a particular message to come in and then spawns the graphical window successfully when ran from the command prompt.

But if I place this in an Upstart .conf file so I can use it as a background service, I can see that my program receives the message to pop up a window but it does not display a graphical window.

```
...
exec /usr/local/bin/vncscript.py # does not display window
...
```

How would I go about displaying a graphical window using Upstart?

Comment: maybe I'm wrong but upstart is use to run services/deamons - programs which can run when nobody is login so there is no posibiliti to display anything. Or maybe you have to set `export DISPLAY=:0.0` to inform program where to display.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with the solution from by setting up a .desktop file:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/107187/how-to-launch-gui-app-with-upstart-script

Initially, I started by a

```
export DISPLAY=0.0
```

...and it worked.  I could then control it as a service.  But as soon as I restarted the computer, it would not work as expected.  Could not even stop the service after starting it.  I'm not sure why it worked in the first place.